# What does it mean by putting (\alpha-\beta) in front of the authors of a paper

Tags: semantics

When I was searching the publication list of some CS researchers, I sometimes saw them putting a ($\alpha-\beta$) or ($\alpha-\beta$ order) in front of the authors of a paper. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you post an example? Can it simply be a symbol to match the authors with their affiliation and contact details? Could they be saying that the authors are listed in lexicographical (alphabetical) order?

Comment: Wild guess: authors are listed in alphabetic order.

Comment: I just checked, it should be alphabetic order.